# How, if at all, can we hide an InputField's DisplayName property with placement.info?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

If we want to hide the `DisplayName` property of an `InputField`, we can override the `InputField`'s default template in our theme. That works. That said, is there a way to use placement.info to do the same?

The following works but we would rather use placement.info for a more concise solution.

**The Default InputField template.**

```
@using Orchard.Fields.Settings;
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
    string value = (string)Model.ContentField.Value;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        string name = Model.ContentField.DisplayName;
    <p class="text-field">@T(name): @value</p>
    }
}
```

**Our Theme's InputField template.**

```
@using Orchard.Fields.Settings;
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
    string value = (string)Model.ContentField.Value;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
    <p class="text-field">@value</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: And you can vote up this work item so you don't have to create templates in all your themes ;) https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already found the standard way of modifying the rendering of the field. Note that you may use alternates such as the one that includes the name of the field, if you only want to target the rendering of particular instances. Placement probably won't be of much help here, except if you need to introduce additional alternates based on a placement match, but in any case, you'll have to use a modified template. The reason why placement can't be used here is that the label is not a content shape in itself and as such can't be targeted by placement.